# split the text only 5 times

Tags: java

i want to split the string ...i want spit to happen for just first 5 times then ...rest in 1 string

i tried this

```
public class FileRead

{  

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
    {  

    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();  
    String str = null;  

    File file = new File("D:\\wokies\\5_dataset.txt");  
    try {  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {  
    String line = scanner.nextLine();  
    System.out.println(line);

     String [] splitSt =line.split(" ");


        System.out.println("split happing");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < splitSt.length ; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(splitSt[i]); 
        }


    }  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: get index of 5th space, and make a substring. Then you could split the first substring into an array if needed.

Comment: Do you want to split *each* line into five parts or do you want to just split the *first five* lines?

Answer (score 2):

I won't write code for you, but the solution is very simple, one solution is to have a counter, initialize it to `0`, increment it on each iteration. When it'll be 5, don't split<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume you want to split each time on a **new** input and not the same one.

Comment: Most preferable solution.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.lang.String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) accepts a limit: How often do you want to split the input?

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.

So

```
line.split(" ", 5);
```

would solve your problem.

Comment: I think he want to split each time on a new input, not the same one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split with limit `split(regex, limit)`. Try maybe `split(" ", 5)`, this will create  array with max 5 elements and last element will not be split like `"a b c d".split(" ", 3)` will create `["a", "b", "c d"]`

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method of `String` can take a second parameter "limit" that "controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array".

Just call `line.split(" ", 5);`

Comment: I think he want to split each time on a new input, not the same one.